# ASP.NET Маршрутизация ссылок

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, route

Каким образом можно создать маршрут: localhost:port/folder?path=S, где S это переменная принимающая значение

```
[Route("Files/[controller]")]
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    IHostingEnvironment _env;
    List<UpdateJson> updateJson = new List<UpdateJson>();

    public UpdateController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    // GET: api/<controller>

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        string contentPath = _env.WebRootPath + "\\Files\\Update\\update.json";
        var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentPath);
        return Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content));
    }
```

при переходе по ссылке возвращается текст с json файла и далее клиентское приложение через ссылку localhost:port/folder?path= сверяет клиентские файлы (апдейтер так сказать)

Пробовал добавить ко второму GET новый роут

```
        // GET api/<controller>/5
    [Route("?path=")]
    [HttpGet("{RelativePath}")]
    public string Get(string RelativePath)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

Но где то я ошибся :D
Только разбираюсь с asp.net, жду критики

Comment: Лично я не уверен, что а) такое можно сделать б) такое вообще стоит делать.

Comment: `[Route("folder")]` + `public string Get(string path)` ?

Comment: @AK l2helper.com/Files/L2Helper при добавлении ?path=DevExpress.Data.v17.2.dll, скачается файл, так что думаю такое можно сделать. а насчет стоит ли, лично я считаю такой путь весьма удобным

Comment: @tym32167 сделать отдельный метод с данным роутом, и далее через него обращаться? я не совсем понял, в данном случае path не переменная, а лишь показывает что задается путь.

Comment: да, path - это имя GET параметра, который вы передаете с запросом, asp.net умеет мапить GET параметры на параметры метода

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что folder - это константа и не будет динамикой?

Comment: `и далее клиентское приложение ... сверяет клиентские файлы` почему бы сверять не хеши файлов?

Comment: @tym32167 да все верно, приложение получает json строку с путем+файл и хеш

Comment: @AK я наконец понял, получается '[Route("Update")]
        [HttpGet("{path}")]
        public string Get(string path)
        {
            if(path == "1")
            {
                return "1";
            }
            else
            {
                return "value";
            }            
        }' возвращаться 1 будет по пути localhost:44367/Files/Update?path=1, иначе value

Comment: Если работает - оформляйте ответом, возможно пригодится кому-то ещё.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("Update")]
[HttpGet("{path}")]
public ActionResult GetUpdate(string path)
{
     var filePath = _env.WebRootPath + "\\Files\\Update\\" + path;
     var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
     return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

path будет получать значения по ссылке localhost:port/Update?path=value